# Why contours found using findContours() are all broken up into pieces when the Canny Image is so clear?

Tags: python, opencv

On the left is my Canny Image. On the right is my Original Image with the contours marked with different colors.

This is bugging me... Why when the Canny Image is so clear, the cv2.findContours() function is still not giving me a **single enclosing contour that wraps the big rectangle** ??

[image]

Original Input Image:
[image]

My code:

```
# [get colored raw image]
rawIm = cv2.imread("sample1.jpg");

# [gray]
print("--------- Image Modification: Gray and Invert --------")
grayIm = cv2.cvtColor(rawIm, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
grayIm = inverte(grayIm) # invert the black to white

# [blurring]
print("--------- Image Modification: Blur --------")
blurredIm = cv2.medianBlur(grayIm, 5);

# [dilate]
print("--------- Image Modification: Dilated --------")
kernel = np.ones((7,7), np.uint8)
dilatedIm = cv2.dilate(blurredIm, kernel, iterations=1)

# [get edges]
cannyIm = cv2.Canny(dilatedIm, lowThreshold, lowThreshold*cannyThresholdRatio)

# [FIND CONTOURS]
cnts, hier = cv2.findContours(cannyIm.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# [DRAW CONTOURS]
for cnt in cnts:
        color = (random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255))
        cv2.drawContours(rawIm, [cnt], -1, color , 6)

cv2.imshow("CANNY", resize(cannyIm, percentageShrink))
cv2.imshow("CONTOURS", resize(rawIm, percentageShrink))
```

Is this problem?

```
cv2.findContours(cannyIm.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Must I use different parameters, other than "cv2.RETR_LIST" and "cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE"?

Comment: Perhaps you should scale the image on the left. It is probably float and needs to be converted to uint8 for saving to files. That is why it looks black and you do not see your data. The possibly use morphology to ensure that the canny edge is fully connected.

Comment: Please show the input without contours on it.

Comment: Image on the right is input with contours the top 5 biggest area contours. I will try dilation morphology

Comment: We want to see the input without the contour on it, please!

Comment: Sorry, misread your comment. The original input image is in the question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Dilation works. Adding `cannyIm = cv2.dilate(cannyIm, kernel, iterations=1)` after the Canny process did the trick.

Full Code

```
# [get colored raw image]
rawIm = cv2.imread("sample1.jpg");

# [gray]
print("--------- Image Modification: Gray and Invert --------")
grayIm = cv2.cvtColor(rawIm, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
grayIm = inverte(grayIm) # invert the black to white

# [blurring]
print("--------- Image Modification: Blur --------")
blurredIm = cv2.medianBlur(grayIm, 5);

# [dilate]
print("--------- Image Modification: Dilated --------")
kernel = np.ones((7,7), np.uint8)
dilatedIm = cv2.dilate(blurredIm, kernel, iterations=1)

# [get edges]
cannyIm = cv2.Canny(dilatedIm, lowThreshold, lowThreshold*cannyThresholdRatio)
cannyIm = cv2.dilate(cannyIm, kernel, iterations=1)

# [FIND CONTOURS]
cnts, hier = cv2.findContours(cannyIm.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# [DRAW CONTOURS]
for cnt in cnts:
        color = (random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255))
        cv2.drawContours(rawIm, [cnt], -1, color , 6)

cv2.imshow("CANNY", resize(cannyIm, percentageShrink))
cv2.imshow("CONTOURS", resize(rawIm, percentageShrink))
```

Thank you @fmw42

[image]

Comment: I think you can avoid the canny edges and just get the contours from a binary threshold after morphology.